# Are there any load meters available for my main electric panel?

Tags: electrical

I have a 200A main coming into the house (Bryant-type panel, which is basically GE now) and was wondering if there is a digital/analog load meter that could be hooked up? I have a clamp meter now, to test circuits, and know that Reliant makes these for 30A/50A generator feeds, but is there a good one that I could use on the main?

I've seen some pictures of digital/lcd in a 2gang box, connected via metal conduit, and put it above the panel, but wasn't sure if there is a good brand or page with instructions on these. I assume that it was just a digital/analog meter and they run the clamp through the conduit, attaching around one side of the main.

Comment: Just a note. Bryant is definitely NOT "basically GE now". The modern equivalent is Cutler-Hammer BR Series.

Comment: Some products are made that look at the outside meter directly. Some newer meters make this easier. Murata makes a nice 4-function (Volts-Amps-[PF or Freq]- Power) but it tops out at 100 Amps.

Comment: One thing you could consider doing, if average current draw over a period of time was a useful data point for you, is that you could take a reading off your utility power meter at say 8:00AM and at 8:00PM for several days in a row. The differences between each of these readings would show kWh usage over each 12 hour span. Divide the reading by 12 to get the average kW utilized per hour. Further divide that by your AC line voltage to derive the average kA consumed per hour. kA of course meaning 1000A so 0.1kA would be 100A.

Comment: Seconding Speedy -- my grandmother has a Westinghouse BR panel, and it has a mix of Westinghouse, Bryant, and C-H BR breakers in it.  (Eaton BRs are the same thing as Cutler-Hammer -- Eaton bought C-H a while back.)

Comment: Also -- have you considered simply asking your electrical utility for a smarter meter?

Comment: Speedy Petey, ah, I thought it was GE since Rexal gave me GE (Q-style?) breakers and they fit right in.